# Pandas read_csv does not raise exception for bad lines when names is specified

Tags: python, pandas

**pandas** **read_csv** raises an exception (**error_bad_lines**) when encountering lines with too many fields. However, this does not happen when the argument *names* is specified..

Example a csv file with the format:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3, 4
```

read with pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None) correctly raises *ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4* due to the additional column.

However, when 'names' is specified as an argument:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(filepath, names=['A', 'B', 'C'], header=None)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
```

there is no error raised and the 'too long/bad' line which should be skipped is included...

Is there a way to specify names and still have the ParserError be raised such that the too long/bad lines can be dropped with error_bad_lines=False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no tidy pandas solution to this. What you could do is load the file CSV with python's `open()` and then add a new header to the file string, in this way you will not modify the original file on the disk. After that you can load the file string with `StringIO` with pandas. This will preserve the error:

```
#python3
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
lines = open('./test.csv', 'r').readlines()
lines = ['A, B, C'] + lines
fileString = '\n'.join(lines)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fileString), sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

To make an educated guess based on your input example: The behavior you are experiencing may be due to the fact that you implicitly tell `pd.read_csv` to set `len(usecols) = len(names)`. As a result, the column that causes your initial Exception will not be imported.

You will get your initial Exception back when you add as much header names to `names` as you have columns present in the csv-file:

```
# 1. Determine maximum column count
    sep = ','                                                   # Define separator
    lines = open(filepath).readlines()                        # Open file and read lines
    colcount = max([len(l.strip().split(sep)) for l in lines])  # Count separator

# 2. Add column headers
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, names = range(colcount))
    # you can rename your columns of interest here in case of error_bad_lines = False
```

Now, the column with missing values will be included and your Exception will come back. Note that this way of counting the maximum number of columns only works for .csv files.